# Transposing lists in python getting a wrong list

Tags: python-3.x, list, transpose

I have been trying to understand how exactly a list would be transposed and one way I found is the function named "transpose_not_working" and another way I see in similar posts is the function called "transponse_working". The output I'm getting for the first function is wrong but I can't quite understand where it goes wrong. It seems to me that the first function is just an extended way of writing the second one. Where exactly did I mess up? I just can't see where my mistake is.

```
def transpose_not_working(l):
 result = [[0]*len(l)]*len(l[0])
 for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l[0])):
        result[j][i] = l[i][j]
 print(result)
 return

def transpose_working(l):
 result = [[l[j][i] for j in range(len(l))] for i in range(len(l[0]))]
 print(result)

matrix = [
[0, 1],
[1, 3],
[2, 5]
]
transpose_not_working(matrix)
transpose_working(matrix)

Output:
[[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have

`result = [[0]*len(l)]*len(l[0])`

You are making shallow copies of `[0]` and `[[0]*len(l)]`

You can see that in your result you get `[[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]`, the two rows are duplicate. Shallow copies cause the fact that modying an element in the original object will also modify it in the shallow copy. So you need a better way to initiate the result variable that doesn't involve shallow copies.

Rewritten code:

```
def transpose_not_working(l):
 n = len(l)
 m = len(l[0])
 result = [ [ 0 for i in range(n) ] for j in range(m) ]
 for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l[0])):
        result[j][i] = l[i][j]
 print(result)
 return
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now.  The lists inside "result" are referencing each other so any change made to one changes the other? And to fix this I need to make sure that each list inside "result" is initiated in a way that doesn't reference another list.
I came up with this way of initiating the list, would there be any way to make this intiating list cleaner?
`code
result = []
    for i in range(len(l[0])):
        result.append([None] * len(l))
`

Comment: I would do it like this
``n = len(l); m = len(l[0]);result = [ [ 0 for i in range(n) ] for j in range(m) ]``